# jQuery hover event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Code sample given below:

```
(function (window, document) {
$('.rating_title_container').parents('.item_row_def').hover(function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
              system.console('Worked');
          }, 1000);
        });
 })(window, document);
```

I am fairly new to JS, jQuery. Can anyone explain what I am missing here?
Posted code in http://jsfiddle.net/p7gBy/5/

HTML

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="item_row_def" onclick="sort(3);">
          <table class="col-header">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <h2 class="header_title rating_title_container">Rating</h2>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: this code runs right away when you called it, if it is in head the rest of the document is not ready yet, so it could not find any elements

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Added it to jsfiddle (in question)

Answer (score 0):

Try following which suppose to call code when the document is ready:

```
jQuery(function (window, document) {
$('.rating_title_container').parents('.item_row_def').hover(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          system.console('Worked');
      }, 1000);
    });
});
```

and meanwhile you have exceeded `});` at the end, which throw an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to be binding your event handlers inside a doc ready like this (replace the code above with this and see):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rating_title_container').parents('.item_row_def').hover(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          system.console('Worked');
      }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
(function (window, document) {
$('.rating_title_container').parents('.item_row_def').hover(function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
              alert('Worked');
          }, 1000);
        });

})(window, document);
```

Check on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AXepU/

Answer (score 0):

you have to enclose that function `doc ready` then all will work fine:

```
$(function(){ // <----------------------------try enclosing within this from here
   (function (window, document) {
      $('.rating_title_container').parents('.item_row_def').hover(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Worked');
        }, 1000);
      });
   })(window, document); 
}); //<---------------------------------------- to here.
```

Most of the events should be written inside `document ready` handler.

this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Handler for .ready() called. 
});
```

and this:

```
$(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

are same. Second one is just shorter version of `doc ready` handler.

[Read More about .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

Comment: same thing you can either `select jQuery from the left top panel` or `put a reference in the dom` with `doc-ready`

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/p7gBy/7/ find the top left of the sidebar where you have to select `ready function` and `framework`.